# How to change settings in a Java war file on Azure release pipeline for tomcat

Tags: java, azure, gradle, tomcat, pipeline

In .Net this is easy - we have a file transformation task. I am trying to do same in Azure dev ops release pipeline with Java but because it’s a war file I not sure how to proceed. I need to set the dB connection for TEST server and changed for PRODUCTION server.

1. I build war file using gradle in azure build pipeline (no problems here)
2. I then can in azure dev ops create a release pipeline that picks up the war and will copy it to tomcat/webapps to install
3. My problem is I have a settings file with DB connection in. That changes depending upon what server it’s going on. I want to use Azure file transformation task but problem I have is all I have is a .war file.

How could I have one build and then change the dB connection/settings file depending upon server it’s being deployed to in the azure release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in the end using tomcat connection (jndi) which can be specified in tomcat so then problem goes away